# Linked List: Data type mismatch

Tags: java, linked-list

I know the problem with my code is (should be) stupid. But would appreciate all help.

[image]

```
public void transferFrom(LinkedIntList list2) {

   // Point to first node of list1
   ListNode current = front;

   // Move to the last node of list1
   while(current != null) {
      current = current.next;
   }

   // Last node of list1 -> firs node of list2
   current.next = list2;

   list2 = null;

}
```

Problem line is `current.next = list2;`. Data type mismatch because `current.next` is `ListNode` and `list2` is `LinkedIntList`.

If I rather use `current.next = list2;`, I get `NullPointerException` for this line.

What should I be doing?

**EDIT**: Fixed!

```
public void transferFrom(LinkedIntList list2) {

   // Point to first node of list1
   ListNode current = front;

   // Move to the last node of list1
   while(current != null && current.next != null) {
      current = current.next;
   }

   // Last node of list1 -> first node of list2
    if(front == null) {
        front = list2.front;
    } else {
        current.next = list2.front;
   }

   list2.front = null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you posted the class definitions for `LinkedIntList` and `ListNode`, and also told us what this method is actually supposed to be doing. But I'm assuming that a `LilnkedIntList` contains a `ListNode front` member and that you are trying to append the contents of `list2` to `this` (which is another `LinkedIntList`). Your troublesome line should probably be:

```
current.next = list2.front;
```

However, you have another problem: your `while` loop is guaranteed to exit with `current == null`, which is not what you want at all. The loop condition should be `(current.next != null)`, not `(current != null)`.

Finally, if you want to empty out `list2`, the way to do it is `list2.front = null;`. Assigning to `list2` inside the method does nothing.

Here's a version of your code incorporating all of my suggestions:

```
public void transferFrom(LinkedIntList list2) {

   if (front == null) {
       front = list2.front;
   } else {
       // Point to first node of list1
       ListNode current = front;

       // Move to the last node of list1
       while(current.next != null) {
          current = current.next;
       }

       // Last node of list1 -> firs node of list2
       current.next = list2;
   }

   // empty out list2
   list2.front = null;

}
```

Comment: `current.next = list2.front;` causes a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @KaranGoel - At least you're past the data type mismatch problem. Did you modify the `while` loop as I suggested?

Comment: Yup, corrected the while loop, and things works fine for some cases. However, `[] transferFrom [8, 17, 2, 4]` gives a `NullPointerException` because `current.next` would mean the `next` of `null`. How can I solve that?

Comment: @KaranGoel - You need to put a special test at the beginning for the case that `front == null`. If that's the case, just assign `front = list2.front` and skip the `while` loop and assignment to `current.next`.

Comment: @KaranGoel - I updated my answer to show the effect of all my suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

you want to move down the list while current.next isn't equal to null. Otherwise you "jump" off of the list onto a null pointer.

For example...

```
while(current.next != null){

 current = current.next

}
```

Once the next node is null the loop will exit and `current` will equal the last node on the list.

So, that'll get you as far as your last element of list one. Then just append all of the elements of list 2 to the end of list one (hint: current should point to the first element of list 2)

**EDIT**

As Ted Hopp stated below the info you're giving on your particular linkedlist implementations is kinda spotty so I'll explain a general case..

You should assign current to be equal to the node you current have in storage. This should probably begin as the first node in the list. In your example above you seem to be doing that but I have no idea where your `front` comes from. Where is it assigned its value? Where is it declared? I'd guess your front is null probably because you're pointing it at the front node incorrectly.

Comment: `[] transferFrom [8, 17, 2, 4]` gives a `NullPointerException` because `current.next` would mean the `next` of `null`. How can I solve that?

Comment: You're probably not assigning `current` to be anything.. `current` should begin as the "first" node in the list.

Comment: From OP, `ListNode current = front;`.. Anyhow, fixed the problems with some changes!